# Sequelize multiply between two columns in model

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, sequelize.js

How do I multiply two columns (quantity * unit) of a table by findAll of sequelize

```
Products.findAll({ 
    attributes: 
    [
        'id',    
        'Product', 
        'Quantity', 
        'Unit'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sequelize.literal** for calculation of some SQL expression (subquery, math calculation etc.):

```
Products.findAll({ 
    attributes: 
    [
        'id',    
        'Product', 
        'Quantity', 
        'Unit',
        [sequelize.literal('(Quantity*Unit)'), 'Cost']
    ]
});
```

To access all attributes includeing calculated in sequelize.literal just map results calling **get({ plain: true })**.

```
const plainProductObjects = products.map(x => x.get({ plain: true })
```

Comment: Ok. It worked. It generates the SQL and plays on the console: SELECT `products`.`id`,` products`.`Product`, `products`.`Quantity`,` products`.`Unity`, (Quantity * Unit) AS `Cost `FROM` products`;
But when I render (in EJS), all fields are displayed except the Cost field:

<% products.forEach( product => { %>
<tr>
    </td>
    <td><%= product.id %></td>
    <td><%= product.Product %></td>
    <td><%= product.Quantity %></td>
    <td><%= product.Unity %></td>
    <td><%= product.Cost %></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>

Comment: try to get plain objects like this `products.map(x => x.get({ plain: true })`

Comment: I can't display the content of 'Cost' on the HTML page (<% = product.Cost%>). The value appears as null. But if I run the SQL below, the Cost value is displayed in MySQL

Comment: Can you look at plainProductObjects?

Comment: Anatoly... At the end of my Product.FindAll, right after the where clause, I put raw: true. And now the Cost field appears, but as this one Join the anotherTable.model.Description field is no longer appearing.

Comment: Problem solved. After I put raw: true, I also put nest: true and now everything works again. Thank you all so much for your help !!!!